# autocomplete off attribute is not working with bootstrap

Tags: html, razor, autocomplete

I am using MVC 4, jQuery and Bootstrap plugin but I want to off the suggestion words, so I put **autocomplte="off"** but it is not working. Please suggestion me

My razor code is

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer_Username, new { id = "logusrname",@autocomplete="off", @class = "form-control", @role = "form", @placeholder = "Username" })
```

[image]

Comment: Do you face this problem in all the browsers?

Comment: @Ruby  Yes, It will solve when I remove the **ID** and **password**

Comment: Try putting autocomplete off attribute to form. Otherwise, there must be some conflict in js

Comment: Try camelcase: autoComplete